# laravel connect to redis container

Tags: laravel, docker, redis

I have 2 laravel projects with 2 docker-compose files docker-compose-1.yml and docker-compose-2.yml. And I want these two projects connect the same redis container in docker-compose-1.yml. 
The env file are same:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

docker-compose-1.yml:

```
redis:
      build:
        context: ./docker/redis
      volumes:
        - ./docker/docker-runtime/redis/data:/data
      expose:
        - "6379"
```

At last project1 has succeed connected to redis. But project 2 failed. The error message:

```
Predis \ Connection \ ConnectionException
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379]
```

How should the project2 connect to redis?

Comment: via a same network. make your own network and have the apps connect to it.